# Filter ng-repeat into specific sections

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object (Vehicles) which contains a list of objects (Vehicle). Each Vehicle object contains attributes (make, model, color, retCode).

```
Object (Vehicles)
0: Object (Vehicle)
    $$hashKey: "object:163"
    make: "Ford"
    model: "Mustang"
    color: "White"
    retCode: "1"
    __proto__: Object
1: Object (Vehicle)
        $$hashKey: "object:164"
        make: "Chevrolet"
        model: "Corvette"
        color: "Red"
        retCode: "2"
    __proto__: Object
2: Object (Vehicle)
        $$hashKey: "object:165"
        make: "Pontiac"
        model: "Firebird"
        color: "Black"
        retCode: "3"
        __proto__: Object
```

On the UI side, I have a form that has fieldsets for each make.

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend>Ford</legend>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to populate the form using ng-repeat, but I want the vehicles to appear in the appropriate fieldsets. For example, I want all the Vehicle objects with the "make" attribute of "Ford" to appear in the Ford fieldset. I'm assuming I have to use a filter, but I have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use filter by key and value

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend>Ford</legend>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="vehicle in Vehicles | filter:{make:'Ford'}">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

May be my syntax can be wrong.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!